# Purely Functional Equivalent of B-Tree?

Tags: ds.data-structures, functional-programming, db.databases

I am exploring the idea of writing a DBMS in purely functional way. The traditional data structure used for indexing is B-Tree. I'd like to know some purely functional equivalent of B-Tree that would be optimized to minimize disk access. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about it, but [this](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~bender/pub/cache-oblivious-btree.ps) seems like a reasonable place to start.

Comment: Mechko, I think cache-oblivious data structures generally are not amenable to purely functional implementations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know more about purely-functional data structures than external-memory data structures, but I'll give this a go.

A B-tree can be written in a purely-functional way by path copying. The path will be short ($O(\log_B n)$), but copying each block takes $O(B)$ writes in $O(1)$ blocks.

If you're willing to let the structure be just fully persistent, rather than purely functional, I think you can reduce the number of writes in a node copy to $O(\lg w)$ expected amortized, where $w$ is the word width, using [the fully persistent arrays in "Confluently Persistent Tries for Efficient Version Control"](http://erikdemaine.org/papers/ConfluentTries_Algorithmica/)

You might want to watch [this presentation about RethinkDB](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDHc3lkr3Ns), which uses purely-functional data structures because of the cost of writes in SSDs.

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in writing a purely functional database, you should probably check out Phil Trinder's [PhD thesis](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.52.4456) which was on this very subject.  He has a chapter on the use of B-Trees.

Comment: Citeseer link seems unresponsive. The thesis is also [here](https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:1fa54dcc-1188-40c9-aa2f-ce2c989e7bd3/download_file?file_format=application%2Fpdf&safe_filename=603849251.pdf&type_of_work=Thesis),